# Mulesoft Dataweave - can't use variable defined in "Using" operator in an "otherwise" clause

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave

Why doesn't this work in Dataweave 1.0?

```
dw( ' using (zone="Z1,Z2") (zone splitBy ",")[0] when "NJ,NY" contains "MA" otherwise (zone splitBy ",")[1] ' )
```

If I put `contains "NJ"` or `contains "NY"`, it executes the `when` clause without a problem, but the `otherwise` produces an error when it has a reference to my `zone` variable.

Is it a scoping thing?   `zone` isn't available for the `otherwise` clause?

I can't find any decent documentation on `using`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a set of parenthesis right after your localized declaration (i.e. `zone`) to indicate its scope.

I tried your code inside a Transform Message processor, this is what should look like when properly indented:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/dw
---
using (
    zone="Z1,Z2"
) (
    (zone splitBy ",")[0] when "NJ,NY" contains "MA" otherwise (zone splitBy ",")[1]
)
```

Always write `using` as follows: `using (<declarations>) (<expression>)`

Your code should be written as follows:

```
#[dw( ' using (zone="Z1,Z2") ((zone splitBy ",")[0] when "NJ,NY" contains "MA" otherwise (zone splitBy ",")[1]) ' )]
```

Here's where the documentation is: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/dataweave-language-introduction#scoped-variables